# IE deletes new option 'text' when using insertBefore

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am trying to add an option dynamically to a select box.

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
elem.insertBefore(new Option("newText", "aValue"), elem.options[x]);
```

where elem is a select element.

The new option is added to the select element with a value of "aValue" but it's text is set to "", when it should be "newText".  I am using IE8.   Can anybody help?

Comment: The `HTMLSelectElement` has an `add` method. Use it.

Comment: Yes, the above line of code works in FF.
Also, I am aware of the add method but from what I understand, the second argument in add is different for IE and FF.  I need to support both browsers and would like to use only 1 line of code.